# Intent and Firebase error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent

I have a problem with new intent work on Firebase. I did new intent it's normally working but i wrote firebase connection code and the app. has stopped error. But Firebase connection working new project but i don't working 2 project together. Please help me.

First Screen

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.btn)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Quiz.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Quiz Screen

```
private Button mButtonChoice1,mButtonChoice2,mButtonChoice3,mButtonChoice4;

private int mScore;
private String mAnswer;

private Firebase mQuestionRef, mchoiceRef,mChoice2Ref,mChoice3Ref,mChoice4Ref,mAnswerRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);mQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(question);





    mQuestionRef = new Firebase("https://fog-alarm.firebaseio.com/0/question")

    mQuestionRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String question = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mQuestion.setText(question);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Also: I **highly** recommend that you use the latest Firebase version on new projects. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem. i'm just forget to add  android:name=".QuizEng"> in android manifest.xml.